# How to get thumbnail image from USB connected phone?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to get a thumbnail image(as shown in the picture link below) of USB connected phone without copying that image to PC?  if yes please help me how to access this thumbnail.

[image: Image property]

Following is the code I am trying to copy thumbnail but it is taking equal time as copying,

```
    private void ThumbJob()
    {
        var files = device.GetFiles(str);
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            if (item.Contains(".JPG"))
            {
                try
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    device.DownloadFile(item, memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

                    Size thumbnailSize = GetThumbnailSize(img);

                    // Get thumbnail.
                    Image thumbnail = img.GetThumbnailImage(thumbnailSize.Width,
                        thumbnailSize.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

                    thumbnail.Save(@"D:\New folder\" + imgs.ToString() + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                catch
                {

                }


            }
            imgs++;
        }
    }

    static Size GetThumbnailSize(Image original)
    {
        const int maxPixels = 40;
        int originalWidth = original.Width;
        int originalHeight = original.Height;

        double factor;
        if (originalWidth > originalHeight)
        {
            factor = (double)maxPixels / originalWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            factor = (double)maxPixels / originalHeight;
        }
        return new Size((int)(originalWidth * factor), (int)(originalHeight * factor));
    }
```

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann sorry my bad but just edited and added the codes I am using, thanks for correcting me.